# Color Text in Rich Text Box in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have Rich TextBox to Edit XML Text
What i want how to color the XML Tags Names inside the RichTextBox 

I want the tags names in RED or Green color.
Any Way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want a syntax editor which handles XML formatted documents?

Answer (score 2):

Work out what your desired regex is using [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Once you have this you could use something like the following method to update the `RichTextBox`

```
public static void HighlightSyntax(RichTextBox richTextBox, Regex yourRegex, Color someColor)
{
    richTextBox.BeginUpdate();
    int selPos = richTextBox.SelectionStart;
    richTextBox.SelectAll();
    richTextBox.SelectionColor = normTextColor;
    richTextBox.Select(selPos, 0);

    // For each match from the regex, highlight the word.
    foreach (Match keyWordMatch in yourRegex.Matches(richTextBox.Text))
    {
        richTextBox.Select(keyWordMatch.Index, keyWordMatch.Length);
        richTextBox.SelectionColor = someColor;
        richTextBox.Select(selPos, 0);
        richTextBox.SelectionColor = normTextColor;
    }
    richTextBox.EndUpdate();
}
```

You could also adopt a timer to update this automatically after a set time.

I hope this helps.

Note. For large text files, and approach like this will be slow! In this case I would adopt Sinctilla.NET as a full syntax highlighter as stated in one of the answers below...

Answer (score 1):

there are articles which explain or suggest possible approaches to syntax colouring, for example: [How To Implement Syntax Highlighting In A WinForms Application](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57072-syntax-highlight-in-c#/)

I think the best and easiest way is to use [Scintilla.NET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) to handle that so you can focus on what really matters to you instead of reinventing the wheel again :)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN created a simple C# function that formats the text content from a RichTextBox:
[LINK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cobold/archive/2011/01/31/xml-highlight-in-richtextbox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/), a nice source code editing component for Windows which supports Syntax Highlighting too. And there's a .NET wrapper for it called [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple regex find the location (start and end) of each tag and colorize it like below:

```
richtextbox1.Select(start, end-start);

richtextbox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;

richtextbox1.Select(start, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for small syntax highlighting projects, roll your own! There are some examples of highlighting in a syntax editor already posted.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13007641/1033686

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13007710/1033686

For larger projects that demand better highlighting, use Scintilla.NET (but be warned, it it a bit heavy and can be tricky to get working!)

http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

For enterprise projects use a commercial product like actipro syntax editor.

http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/windowsforms/syntaxeditor?gclid=CI6rrqmglLMCFSfMtAodbE8AhA